# How to draw the structure and find the oxidation number of Phosphorous in H2P2O7

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, oxidation-state, lewis-structure

**Find the Oxidation number of Phosphorus in $\ce{H2P2O7^2-}$.**

So I thought of drawing the lewis structure to find the oxidation numbers. Because I wasn't sure if *Oxygen was bonded to a Hydrogen* or not. Then I realised that the two Hydrogens could be ionised, so I'd be left with $\ce{P2O7^4-}$.

But then when I tried drawing this Lewis structure I got really confused, As I tried to draw it with the two Phosphorus as central atoms and I couldn't make it. (I know I can just use general rules to find oxidation numbers but I feel like lewis structures often give more accurate answers). So could you please tell me **how to draw the structure and more importantly guide me through the process**. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please use [$\LaTeX$](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/good-idea-for-editing-meta-post-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions?cb=1) and also see [How to ask a good question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You have O and P, both in their most common valence states. You start connecting them until there is nothing more to connect. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Take 2 dihydrogenphosphate anions and condense 2 OH groups ( 1 from each ion ) into -O- bridge, eliminating water.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't understand what  Poutnik has sain in his comment, this is how it should be done:

You have realized your parent compound is $\ce{H4P2O7}$ (adding two $\ce{H+}$). Correct? If so, concentrate on following hypothetical reaction:

$$\ce{2H3PO4 -> H4P2O7 + H2O} \tag1$$

I believe you know what $\ce{H3PO4}$ is looks like. Now, draw two $\ce{H3PO4}$ side by side. Choose two closest $\ce{OH}$ groups (that would be $\ce{-P-\color{red}{OH} \space \space \color{tequish}{HO}-P -}$). Then, remove one $\ce{\color{red}{-OH}}$ and the $\ce{\color{tequish}{-H}}$ from the second $\ce{\color{tequish}{-OH}}$ you chose to eliminate a $\ce{H2O}$ molecule. Finally combine two remaining molecules together such that final structure forms $\ce{-P\color{red}{-}\color{tequish}{O}-P -}$ bond. This is your $\ce{H4P2O7}$. Eliminate any two hydrogens to get $\ce{H2P2O7^2-}$ structure.

**Note:** Since above hypothetical equation $(1)$ does not require oxidation or reduction to form $\ce{H4P2O7}$, it is safe to assume that oxidation state of $\ce{P}$ in both $\ce{H3PO4}$ and $\ce{H4P2O7}$ is same.